# Menu Toggle Element

Tags: html, css

I'm reworking a WHMCS menu to be responsive and touch sensitive. Everything is fine except for one thing. I can't get the proper elements to display/toggle properly.

What the jQuery script does is add "open" class to parent element onclick. So

```
<div id="menu-icon"><a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Menu</a></div>
```

Becomes:

```
<div id="menu-icon" class="open"><a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Menu</a></div>
```

When the "Menu" link is clicked.

I need the "#nav" to "display:none" by default, and "display:block" when Menu is clicked. I can't quite capture it via CSS.

My HTML

```
<nav id="nav-wrap">
<div id="menu-icon"><a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Menu</a></div>
<ul id="nav">
```

My CSS

```
#nav-wrap #nav {
    display: none;
}
#nav-wrap #menu-icon.open #nav {
    display: block;
}
```

With the code above, I can hide the #nav by default, but that's it. Any pointers on how to capture #nav?

Comment: Did you preview your question to see if it displays everything correctly?

Comment: The CSS you have written is absolutely correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Boss, there is fundamental mistake you have done.

You have given this code:

```
<nav id="nav-wrap">
    <div id="menu-icon">
        <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Menu</a>
    </div>
    <ul id="nav">​
```

See, the `#nav` doesn't come under `#menu-icon`. Change the code to:

```
<nav id="nav-wrap">
    <div id="menu-icon">
        <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Menu</a>
        <ul id="nav">​
    </div>
```

And it works!

#### Demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/qqbUY/

#### Screenshot

[image]

Comment: the code I posted is is using a media query for less than 600px; If I do as you suggested, then it wrecks the menu above 600px. I can't wrap the list in a div.

Comment: @user1681191 Can we see any kind of demo?

Comment: xarhosting.com WIP. resize window(less than 600px) to see the problem.

Comment: Ah I get it. Gimme some time, will fix it up! :)

Comment: My previous attempt was to just use jQuery, but it didn't work. Script here: http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/mobile-navigation-design-tutorial

Comment: Lemme try it out. Even it fails here. :(

Comment: Did you notice that the Account in the right most is not responsive?

Comment: I asked you to keep the `#nav` inside the `#menu`. Can you do that?

Comment: @user1681191 See the answer above, move the `#nav` inside the `#menu`.

Comment: I put the #nav inside the #menu, it breaks everything. I reckon that's the only way to do it, which requires me to rewrite alot of the CSS

Comment: One thing is, that the `<a>` should be a sibling before `#nav`. Is that possible? What is it breaking if you do that way, will fix that too! :)